# Total charge from a charge density

Tags: electrostatics, charge, density, dirac-delta-distributions, dipole

I was trying to calculate the total charge from a charge density that has a very strange form involving delta functions. The charge density is

$$\rho(\vec r) = - \vec d . \nabla \delta(\vec r)$$

$d$ is a vector in 3 dimensions. How to find the integral of such a function?

Comment: Integrate by parts. It's a dipole distribution, so you should ge that the total charge is zero.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since this is a simple enough problem to do, I'll do it in one dimension and let you do it in three! In one dimension, $$\rho(x) = -d \frac{\text{d}}{\text{d} x} \delta (x).$$

The derivative of the delta function (very much like the delta function itself) is only properly defined when you act it on a function. It's easy to show (using integration by parts) that

$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x)\,\,\delta'(x - x_0)\,\, \text{d} x = - f'(x_0),$$ meaning that while the delta function "picks out" the value of the function at $x_0$, the derivative of the delta function picks out the (negative of the) value of the function's *derivative* at $x_0$! Using this, it should be easy to see that $$Q = \int_{-\infty}^\infty \rho(x)\,\text{d} x = + \frac{\text{d}}{\text{d} x} (d) = 0,$$ if $d$ is a constant. I leave it to you to see how this generalises (very simply!) to three dimensions.